# Вывод строк со случайным таймаутом

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Хочу вывести строку через случайное количество времени. После ее вывода в той же строке выводится еще слово через случайное количество времени. После чего выводится вторая строка по такому же принципу.

Пример:

1. Запуск программы;
2. Выводится строка через случайное время "Моя первая основная строка...";
3. Выводится дополнительная часть в этой же строке "Моя основная строка...Дополнительная строка номер 1";
4. Выводится строка через случайное время "Моя вторая основная строка...";
5. Выводится дополнительная часть в этой же строке "Моя основная вторая...Дополнительная строка номер 1"

Основные части в этой строке разные, но Дополнительные одинаковые, хоть это и не так важно. Есть идея сделать через **мультипроцессинг** или же через **управление потоками**.

Есть ли другой способ?

Comment: Зачем тут потоки/процессы?

Comment: @mkkik сразу пришло в голову. Можно было бы для Основной строки задать время например 1сек < n < 5сек,а Дополнительной строке 5сек < k < 10сек. Как вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно просто заснуть на нужное время

```py
import time
import random

time.sleep(random.random() * 3)
print('Основная1... ', end='', flush=True)

time.sleep(random.random() * 3)
print('Дополнительная1')

time.sleep(random.random() * 3)
print('Основная2... ', end='', flush=True)

time.sleep(random.random() * 3)
print('Дополнительная2')
```

Чтобы программа не простаивала в между выводом строк, можно организовать вывод по [таймеру](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects).
Hо при этом также будут задействованы потоки: `Timer` потомок `Thread`